# Handle is invalid

Tags: c, windows, console

Trying to use `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` but it fails and puts "The handle is invalid." In the last error. Will post all code, but here are some highlights:

Using this to resize buffer:

```c
int TGHandleResizeEvent(struct TGHandle *tgHandle, INPUT_RECORD record) {
    if (record.EventType == WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT) {
        WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD size = record.Event.WindowBufferSizeEvent;
        sizeTGDrawBuffer(&tgHandle->drawBuffer, size.dwSize.X, size.dwSize.Y);
        clearTGDrawBuffer(&tgHandle->drawBuffer);
        COORD bufferNewSize = {
            size.dwSize.X,
            size.dwSize.Y
        };
        return SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(&tgHandle->screenBufferHandle, bufferNewSize);
    }
}
```

Using this to allocate handle:

```c
struct TGHandle TG() {
    struct TGHandle tgHandle;
    tgHandle.screenBufferHandle = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
        NULL
    );
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(tgHandle.screenBufferHandle, &info);
    tgHandle.drawBuffer = createTGDrawBuffer(info.dwSize.X, info.dwSize.Y);
    // Create the input buffer
    tgHandle.inputBufferSize = 32;
    tgHandle.inputBuffer = malloc(sizeof(INPUT_RECORD) * tgHandle.inputBufferSize);
    // Hook up the input handle
    tgHandle.inputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    return tgHandle;
}
```

Here is full code.

#### tg.h

```c
#ifndef TG_H
#define TG_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define FOREGROUND_WHITE FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE
#define BACKGROUND_WHITE BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE

// A drawing buffer, for general purposes
struct TGDrawBuffer {
    COORD size;
    CHAR_INFO *buffer;
};

struct TGDrawBuffer createTGDrawBuffer(int, int); // Function to allocate a drawing buffer
void sizeTGDrawBuffer(struct TGDrawBuffer*, int, int); // Resize a draw buffer
void clearTGDrawBuffer(struct TGDrawBuffer*); // Fill a buffer with blank cells
void TGDrawPixel(struct TGDrawBuffer*, int, int, CHAR_INFO); // Draw to a single cell on the buffer
void TGDrawAttribute(struct TGDrawBuffer*, int, int, int); // Modify a single attribute. X, Y, Attr
void TGDrawCharInfoString(struct TGDrawBuffer*, int, int, CHAR_INFO*, int); // X, Y, string, int. Draws to max X
CHAR_INFO* TGCharToCharInfo(char*, int); // Convert basic characters to CHAR_INFO. String, length.
void TGDrawString(struct TGDrawBuffer*, int, int, char*, int); // X, Y, string, length. Draws to max X
void freeTGDrawBuffer(struct TGDrawBuffer*); // Function to de-allocate a drawing buffer

int CharInfoStrlen(CHAR_INFO*); // Get length of a CHAR_INFO as if it were a string

// Essentially a drawing context to the screen
struct TGHandle {
    HANDLE screenBufferHandle, inputHandle;
    struct TGDrawBuffer drawBuffer;
    INPUT_RECORD *inputBuffer;
    int inputBufferSize;
};

struct TGHandle TG(); // Initialization function, which returns a drawing context to the screen
void useTGHandle(struct TGHandle*); // Make a screen drawing context active
void updateTGHandle(struct TGHandle*); // Displays what has been drawn
void setTGHandleCursorVisibility(struct TGHandle*, int); // True / False
int getTGInput(struct TGHandle*, INPUT_RECORD*, int); // Fill input into a buffer
int getTGNextInput(struct TGHandle*, INPUT_RECORD*); // Get a single INPUT_RECORD or return false
int TGHandleResizeEvent(struct TGHandle*, INPUT_RECORD); // Resize is not handled automatically

#endif
```

#### tg.c

```c
#include "tg.h"
#include <string.h>

struct TGDrawBuffer createTGDrawBuffer(int width, int height) {
    struct TGDrawBuffer tgDrawBuffer;
    tgDrawBuffer.buffer = NULL; // Init the buffer to NULL
    sizeTGDrawBuffer(&tgDrawBuffer, width, height);
    return tgDrawBuffer;
}

void sizeTGDrawBuffer(struct TGDrawBuffer* drawBuffer, int width, int height) {
    // Using free/ malloc here because we aren't interested in retaining data
    if (drawBuffer->buffer) {
        free(drawBuffer->buffer);
    }
    drawBuffer->buffer = malloc(sizeof(CHAR_INFO) * (width * height));
    // Copy the size to the buffer record
    drawBuffer->size.X = width;
    drawBuffer->size.Y = height;
}

void clearTGDrawBuffer(struct TGDrawBuffer *tgBuffer) {
    int i = 0, limit = tgBuffer->size.X * tgBuffer->size.Y;
    // Create a blank CHAR_INFO
    CHAR_INFO clearChar;
    clearChar.Char.AsciiChar = ' ';
    clearChar.Char.UnicodeChar = ' ';
    clearChar.Attributes = FOREGROUND_WHITE; // Would be confusing without this
    // Set everything to that buffer
    while (i < limit) {
        tgBuffer->buffer[i] = clearChar;
        i++;
    }
}

void TGDrawPixel(struct TGDrawBuffer *tgBuffer, int x, int y, CHAR_INFO character) {
    tgBuffer->buffer[(tgBuffer->size.X * y) + x] = character;
}

void TGDrawAttribute(struct TGDrawBuffer *tgBuffer, int x, int y, int attr) {
    tgBuffer->buffer[(tgBuffer->size.X * y) + x].Attributes = attr;
}

void TGDrawCharInfoString(struct TGDrawBuffer *tgDrawBuffer, int x, int y, CHAR_INFO *string, int length) {
    int charsToWrite = length;
    int distanceToEnd = (tgDrawBuffer->size.Y - 1) - y;
    if (distanceToEnd < charsToWrite)
        distanceToEnd = charsToWrite;
    int startPos = x + (tgDrawBuffer->size.X * y);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < distanceToEnd) {
        tgDrawBuffer->buffer[startPos + x] = string[i];
        i++;
    }
}

CHAR_INFO* TGCharToCharInfo(char* string, int length) {
    if (length == -1)
        length = strlen(string);
    // TODO
}

void TGDrawString(struct TGDrawBuffer *tgDrawBuffer, int x, int y, char *string, int length) {
    int charsToWrite = length;
    int distanceToEnd = (tgDrawBuffer->size.Y - 1) - y;
    if (distanceToEnd < charsToWrite)
        charsToWrite = distanceToEnd;
    int startPos = x + (tgDrawBuffer->size.X * y);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < charsToWrite) {
        tgDrawBuffer->buffer[startPos + i].Char.AsciiChar = string[i];
        tgDrawBuffer->buffer[startPos + i].Char.UnicodeChar = string[i];
        i++;
    }
}

void freeTGDrawBuffer(struct TGDrawBuffer *drawBuffer) {
    free(drawBuffer->buffer);
}

struct TGHandle TG() {
    struct TGHandle tgHandle;
    tgHandle.screenBufferHandle = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
        NULL
    );
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(tgHandle.screenBufferHandle, &info);
    tgHandle.drawBuffer = createTGDrawBuffer(info.dwSize.X, info.dwSize.Y);
    // Create the input buffer
    tgHandle.inputBufferSize = 32;
    tgHandle.inputBuffer = malloc(sizeof(INPUT_RECORD) * tgHandle.inputBufferSize);
    // Hook up the input handle
    tgHandle.inputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    return tgHandle;
}

void useTGHandle(struct TGHandle *tgHandle) {
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(tgHandle->screenBufferHandle);
    // Update the buffer sizes
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(tgHandle->screenBufferHandle, &info);
    sizeTGDrawBuffer(&tgHandle->drawBuffer, info.dwSize.X, info.dwSize.Y);
    clearTGDrawBuffer(&tgHandle->drawBuffer);
}

void updateTGHandle(struct TGHandle *tgHandle) {
    COORD size = { tgHandle->drawBuffer.size.X, tgHandle->drawBuffer.size.Y }; // Buffer size
    COORD pos = { 0, 0 }; // Start of the buffer coord
    SMALL_RECT rect = {
        .Left = 0,
        .Top = 0,
        .Right = size.X - 1,
        .Bottom = size.Y - 1
    }; // Rect to draw to on destination
    WriteConsoleOutput(
        tgHandle->screenBufferHandle,
        tgHandle->drawBuffer.buffer,
        size,
        pos,
        &rect
    );
}

void setTGHandleCursorVisibility(struct TGHandle *tgHandle, int visible) {
    // Copy the already-available cursor info
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO info;
    GetConsoleCursorInfo(tgHandle->screenBufferHandle, &info);
    // Modify the cursor visibility
    info.bVisible = visible;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(tgHandle->screenBufferHandle, &info);
}

// You should be able to use a TGHandle's input buffer rather than creating your own
// for maximum memory conservation
int getTGInput(struct TGHandle *tgHandle, INPUT_RECORD *inputBuffer, int max) {
    int availableRecords;
    GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(tgHandle->inputHandle, &availableRecords);
    int amountToRead = max;
    if (availableRecords < max) {
        amountToRead = availableRecords;
    }
    int numberRead;
    ReadConsoleInput(
        tgHandle->inputHandle,
        inputBuffer,
        amountToRead,
        &numberRead
    );
    return numberRead;
}

// This function should be pretty performant if someone would not like to use
// the above function and mess around with buffers.
// Input record info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str
int getTGNextInput(struct TGHandle *tgHandle, INPUT_RECORD *record) {
    int availableRecords;
    GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(tgHandle->inputHandle, &availableRecords);
    if (availableRecords == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    ReadConsoleInput(
        tgHandle->inputHandle,
        tgHandle->inputBuffer,
        1,
        &availableRecords
    );
    *record = tgHandle->inputBuffer[0];
    return 1;
}

int TGHandleResizeEvent(struct TGHandle *tgHandle, INPUT_RECORD record) {
    if (record.EventType == WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT) {
        WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD size = record.Event.WindowBufferSizeEvent;
        sizeTGDrawBuffer(&tgHandle->drawBuffer, size.dwSize.X, size.dwSize.Y);
        clearTGDrawBuffer(&tgHandle->drawBuffer);
        COORD bufferNewSize = {
            size.dwSize.X,
            size.dwSize.Y
        };
        return SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(&tgHandle->screenBufferHandle, bufferNewSize);
    }
}
```

#### test.c

```c
#include "tg.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void getMessageAsStr(char *buf) {
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, GetLastError(), 0,
        buf, 256, NULL);
}

int main() {

    // Error buffer
    char buf[256];

    // Create a drawing context to the screen
    struct TGHandle context = TG();
    useTGHandle(&context);
    setTGHandleCursorVisibility(&context, 0); // Hide the cursor of course
    struct TGDrawBuffer *buffer = &context.drawBuffer;

    // Create a CHAR_INFO to draw with
    CHAR_INFO info;
    info.Attributes = BACKGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_WHITE;
    info.Char.AsciiChar = ' ';
    info.Char.UnicodeChar = ' ';

    INPUT_RECORD input;

    const int STRING_BUF_SIZE = 64;
    char *fpsCountBuffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * STRING_BUF_SIZE);

    long start, end;

    start = QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    int running = 1;
    while (running) {

        // Start off with a nice clean slate
        //clearTGDrawBuffer(buffer);

        // Collect input to react to resize
        while (getTGNextInput(&context, &input)) {
            if (input.EventType == WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT) {
                if (!TGHandleResizeEvent(&context, input)) {
                    OutputDebugString("Couldn't resize:\n");
                    getMessageAsStr(buf);
                    OutputDebugString(buf);
                }
            }
        }

        // Draw line along top and bottom
        int i = 0;
        while (i < buffer->size.X) {
            TGDrawPixel(buffer, i, 0, info);
            TGDrawPixel(buffer, i, buffer->size.Y - 1, info);
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        // Draw vertical lines
        while (i < buffer->size.Y) {
            TGDrawPixel(buffer, 0, i, info);
            TGDrawPixel(buffer, buffer->size.X - 1, i, info);
            i++;
        }

        // FPS count!
        // Get time elapsed in millis
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
        long fps = 1000000 / (end - start);
        // Put it into the screen buffer
        snprintf(fpsCountBuffer, STRING_BUF_SIZE, "Running at %ldhz, %dx%d", fps, buffer->size.X, buffer->size.Y);
        TGDrawString(buffer, 1, 1, fpsCountBuffer, strlen(fpsCountBuffer));
        start = end;

        updateTGHandle(&context);
    }

}
```

Comment: Damn, I see it now. I accidentally am taking the pointer location of the handle, instead of the handle itself.

Comment: Answer your own question! It's accepted on Stack Overflow if you answer your own question, as it might help others having the same problem. Also, please stray away from rude or vulgar language :).

Comment: @JL2210 Apologies. That isn't rude or vulgar where I'm from.

Comment: Okay. You can also edit comments.

Comment: @JL2210 Er, it seems my 5 minute edit period has expired

Comment: You're not allowed to edit comments AFTER five minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Spotted it right after I posted it. You can see that I'm taking the pointer *location* of the handle in `TGHandleResizeEvent`:

```c
return SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(&tgHandle->screenBufferHandle, bufferNewSize);
```

This is, in fact, an invalid handle. Corrected code:

```c
return SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(tgHandle->screenBufferHandle, bufferNewSize);
```